# How do I mark an item as owned in Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I'd like to improve my Amazon recommendations and special gold box deals by marking items that I own. I've done this in the past, and they've changed the item page so I can't find the "I own this" checkbox on the page any longer. It does appear on my recommended items page, but that's the only place I can find it. Is there any other way to mark an arbitrary item as owned?

Comment: I wonder if I could access this information via the Amazon API?

Answer (score 6):

I finally found a good solution today:

Put the product on your wishlist, then go to the wishlist page and delete it, it will basically ask you why you deleted it, and you can can basically say, "because I own it"

[image]

Comment: I don't see an "I own it" checkbox - looks like that functionality has been removed :(

Comment: You can now update the "Has" quantity field on a wish list item to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan You can say "has", but it doesn't appear to update your preferences.

Answer (score 4):

According to [a post](http://www.amazon.com/gp/forum/cd/discussion.html/ref=cm_cd_et_md_pl?ie=UTF8&cdForum=Fx20DX5GEB7TUX8&cdMsgNo=8&cdPage=1&cdSort=oldest&cdThread=Tx1QIKG5CGZWPFP&cdMsgID=Mx3G6HJO2DVH3QP#Mx3G6HJO2DVH3QP) in a Amazon support forum, Amazon customer support mentioned that this feature was removed:

> Unfortunately, the option "I own it" checkbox on the product pages is
> no longer available on our website.

Another [poster](http://www.amazon.com/gp/forum/cd/discussion.html/ref=cm_cd_et_md_pl?ie=UTF8&cdForum=Fx20DX5GEB7TUX8&cdMsgNo=9&cdPage=1&cdSort=oldest&cdThread=Tx1QIKG5CGZWPFP&cdMsgID=Mx2AZ34ZWE4EWWN#Mx2AZ34ZWE4EWWN) mentioned that it is possible to search for items and mark them as owned with this link: http://www.amazon.com/gp/rate-it

Another [post](http://www.amazon.com/gp/forum/cd/discussion.html/ref=cm_cd_et_md_pl?ie=UTF8&cdForum=Fx20DX5GEB7TUX8&cdMsgNo=20&cdPage=1&cdSort=oldest&cdThread=Tx1QIKG5CGZWPFP&cdMsgID=MxIATGR1GNHKCH#MxIATGR1GNHKCH) notes:

> After you mark items in the rate-it wizard - go to the "Items you've
> rated" page and you should see the new items at the top of the list
> with the star ratings you put in and the I-Own-It check box. AFAICT,
> the wizard isn't tied to your account - it's just a tool to input
> data.

So the new tool might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for, and it is a little helpful, but not quite right.

Comment: Also, where is the "Items you've rated" page?

Comment: The various methods discussed on that thread are not reliable.  If you Amazon doesn't want us to be able to do this then there isn't much point in using one of the work-around - only to see the list disappear.  The fact is that they are forcing users to either rate something or like it.  Resistance is futile.

Answer (score 3):

On the [Amazon Betterizer](http://www.amazon.com/gp/betterizer/) you can select 'not intersted' and/or 'i own it' by hovering over the item, like this:

[image: Not interested in The Twilight Saga]

Also, on [recommendations](http://www.amazon.com/gp/yourstore/recs/), the same options are shown:

[image: I own it on Seth Godin book]

Comment: Again great answer, but I'm looking for a way to mark a product I own that is not recommended. :(

Comment: +1 purely for clicking "Not Interested" next to Twilight (and it's a valid answer)

Comment: This no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

See Amazon.com: Your Media Library at http://www.amazon.com/gp/ays

You can mark many different items as part of your library, regardless of whether you purchased them through Amazon or not. There is also an import feature to transfer lists from other services (e.g., LibraryThing).

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't work on non-media items? i.e. how do I tell it I own a shirt?

Comment: Also this doesn't appear to work. They appear to be two separate lists, and don't mark things as owned in amazon. :(

Answer (score 2):

I created a bookmarklet based on [Tahg](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/190387/tahg)'s [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118609):

https://tslivede.github.io/Amazon_I_own_this_Bookmarklet

Just drag the "I own this" link on that page into your browser's "favorites/bookmarks toolbar". When you want to mark an Amazon product as owned, open its product page and click on the "I own this" link in your "favorites/bookmarks toolbar".

---

Just as information:
The bookmarklet is just an easy way to execute the following code in the context of the Amazon product page, without creating a complete browser plugin.

```
x=new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET',location.href.replace(
  /^https?:\/\/([^/]*)\.amazon\.([^/]{1,8})\/.*?\/([0-9A-Z]{10})(?![^/]).*/,
  'https://$1.amazon.$2/gp/yourstore/legacy/ratings/submit.html/ref=pd_recs_rate_ioi_ys_ir_all&$3_asin.rating.owned=OWN&'
    +document.cookie.match(/^(?:.*?; )?(session-id=[^;]*)/)[1]
    +'&rating.source=ir&rating_asin=$3&type=asin&return.response=204'),
  false);
x.send();
window.open('/gp/yourstore/iyr/ref=pd_ys_iyr_edit_own?ie=UTF8&collection=owned')
```

Comment: It seems, that I could simplify the bookmarklet by just opening an url like this as a popup: https://www.amazon.de/gp/yourstore/rate-this-asin/ref=atv_hov_why_recommend?ASIN=B072FNLK7Z

Answer (score 1):

This method seems to work reliably, however it requires some bits of info from various places.  Someone that knows how to make a browser extension could probably make an integration fairly easily.

Amazon uses the following link for marking items as owned: https://www.amazon.com/gp/yourstore/legacy/ratings/submit.html/ref=pd_recs_rate_ioi_ys_ir_all&XXXXXXXXXX_asin.rating.owned=OWN&session-id=XXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX&rating.source=ir&rating_asin=XXXXXXXXXX&type=asin&return.response=204

Two bits of info need to be filled in:

1. The product's ASIN. This can be found in the product page's URL, and on the page itself.
2. Session Id. How to find this varies by browser, but you're looking for a cookie with a domain of amazon.com, and a name of session-id.
3. (Optional) If for some reason you want to remove an item from your list of owned items, you can replace OWN with NONE. This should generally be unnecessary though as you can also do this from the Items you own page. I only list it here for anyone wanting to create a tool from this information.

Answer (score 0):

New way to do this (yes, Amazon is *not* making it easy!).

Go to Your Account>Your Recommendations>a set of recommendations>See All. Now all there is on the items is a Similar Items button. However, in the top right of the page, there’s a toggle for Remove Items. Turn it on, and the Similar Items button becomes a Remove button. Click the button, and it opens a dialog box with the choices

0 I already own this item

0 I’m not interested in this item

Click the radio button for the appropriate choice, and OK in the bottom corner.
This option works as of Sept 5, 2021

Comment: This is reasonable for removing things amazon thinks you own. I'm particularly looking for a way to tell amazon: "I own this, use this for recommendations"